# Calling the psql command without selecting any database

Tags: postgresql

The syntax of the `psql` command line client is

```
psql [option...] [dbname [username]]
```

I am passing the command `ALTER DATABASE x RENAME to y` to this command:

```
echo `ALTER DATABASE x RENAME to y` | psql
```

Currently I am getting the error

```
psql: FATAL:  database "myuser" does not exist
```

It looks like the `psql` command tries to open the database with the same name as the current user name.

How can I start the `psql` command without selecting any database?

*Edit*:

A workaround is of course just to create an empty database for the user.

Using the database `x` as a parameter is not working, as this blocks the rename.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try setting the database: `psql -d postgres`:

```
echo `ALTER DATABASE x RENAME to y` | psql -d postgres
```

"template1" or "postgres" should be available.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483139/php-how-do-i-connect-to-postgresql-without-specifying-database-name

Answer (score 1):

**In Ubuntu:**

```
sudo -u postgres psql
postgres=# ALTER DATABASE "old" RENAME TO "new";
ALTER DATABASE
postgres=# \q
```